# I couldn't get that line

Tags: arduino

Can you guys tell me what does it mean that line?

> char next = (i == TERRAIN_WIDTH-1) ? newTerrain : terrain[i+1];

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to this:

```
char next;
if ( i == (TERRAIN_WIDTH - 1) ) {
    next = newTerrain;
} else {
    next = terrain[ i+1 ];
}
```

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: